# $\phi_{w}$ is differentiable in $a,$ if $ r (h) $ depends on $ h$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Definition: Let $V\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$ an open set, $a\in V$ y $f\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a function. We will say that f is differentiable in $a,$ if exists a linear transformation $f′(a)\colon\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
\begin{equation}
f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)(h)+r(h),\qquad\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\dfrac{r(h)}{\lVert h\rVert}}=0.
\end{equation}

Let $V\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$ and $a\in V$ be. They are equivalent

(1). Then the function $A\colon V\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{p})$ is differentiable in $a$

(2). For all $w\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ the function $\phi_{w}\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^{p}$ given by $\phi_{w}(x)=A(x)\cdot w$ is differentiable in $a.$ In this case, $\phi_{w}'(a)\cdot v=(A'(a)\cdot v)\cdot w.$

My attempt:

Suppose $ (1). $ Let $w\in\mathbb{R}^{m}.$ Let's see what $\phi_{w}\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^{p}$ given by $\phi_{w}(x)=A(x)\cdot w$ is differentiable in $a.$ By $(1),$ exists a linear transformation $A′(a)\colon\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{p})$ such that
\begin{equation}
A(a+h)=A(a)+A'(a)(h)+r(h),\qquad\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\dfrac{r(h)}{\lVert h\rVert}}=0.
\end{equation}

From this it follows that

\begin{equation*}
    A(x+h)\cdot w=A(a)\cdot w+A'(a)(h)\cdot w+r(h)\cdot w, \qquad\lim_{h\rightarrow{0}}{\dfrac{r(h)}{\lVert h\rVert}}=0,
\end{equation*}
that is to say,
\begin{equation*}
    \phi_{w}(x+h)=\phi_{w}(a)+(A'(a)\cdot h)\cdot w+r(h)\cdot w,\qquad\lim_{h\rightarrow{0}}{\dfrac{r(h)}{\lVert h\rVert}}=0
\end{equation*}
and $\phi_{w}$ is f is differentiable in $a.$

I did not want to continue because several doubts arose with that test that I wrote. In this case, is the function $ r (h) $ a linear transformation? Also, can't I conclude that $ \phi_{w} $ is differentiable in $ a $ because that $ r(h) $ depends on $ h $?
Any suggestion will be welcome. Also, I would like to know if you have seen that exercise in a book.